# Get WordPress tags from a certain post by its ID?

Tags: php, wordpress, tags

I've searched all over the place and scoured the API. All I'm coming up with are ways to get POSTS by a TAG, but not get the TAGS of a SPECIFIC post by its ID.

What I'm trying to do is pretty simple - I have a post and I want to check if it has a specific tag - 'specialtag' - and then do something on that page if it has this tag. Nothing seems to point me in the right direction. Is there something I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`get_the_tags` will fetch all of the tags for a particular post. It can take a post ID as a parameter for use outside of the loop:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_tags

If all you want to do is determine if a post has a particular tag, you can use `has_tag`:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_tag

```
if( has_tag($tag_slug_or_id, $post_id_or_object) ) {
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 7):

It's simple, you can use `get_the_tags` function like this :

> **CODEX:** The function return an array of objects, one object for each tag assigned to the
>   post.

**Example 1:**

If you have the post ID you can retrieve the tag associated with the post by this code

```
$postid = $post->ID; 
get_the_tags($postid);
```

**Example 2:**

retrieve the tag associated with the post inside the loop

```
$posttags = get_the_tags();
if ($posttags) {
  foreach($posttags as $tag) {
    echo $tag->name . ' '; 
  }
}
```

this function is used in The Loop, then no ID need be passed

**Example 3:**

retrieve the tag associated with the post outside the loop

```
global $post;
   foreach(get_the_tags($post->ID) as $tag) {
      echo $tag->name . ', ';
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get tags by post id you could use the followng function. This will work on anywhere since the method is based on database querying.

```
function sc_tf_get_tags_as_array($post_id){
    global $wpdb;
    $tbl_terms = $wpdb->prefix . "terms";
    $tbl_term_relationships = $wpdb->prefix . "term_relationships";

    $sql = "SELECT name FROM $tbl_terms WHERE term_id in (SELECT term_taxonomy_id FROM $tbl_term_relationships WHERE object_id='$post_id');";
    $results = $wpdb->get_results($sql);

    if($results){
        foreach($results as $row){
            $tags_list[] = $row->name;
        }
    }

    return $tags_list;
}
```